# Oracle SQL - Where Not Exists and multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm in need of some assistance to anyone familiar with Oracle SQL.  I'm trying to use the  Where Not Exists sub query, and is working fine with specific where clauses for specific customers, and then using UNION to join any other customer thereafter.  I'm trying to use the SQL in a way where I'm not using UNION to join multiple customers, as there's 100's.  I just don't know how to go about it.

I think I need to join the MAIN_ITEM table to the LOCATION table somehow, as it links the items in INVENTORY_LOCATIONS with a zone_code where the location_code can be compared against the table ZONE, showing any mismatches where location_code in INVENTORY_LOCATIONS does not exist in table ZONE.  I'm not really sure if I"m explaining this properly, but hopefully my example below clears it up.

Many thanks in advance.

Current Query

```
select a.company, a.customer, c.customer_name, a.location_code, a.invt1, a.invt2, a.invt3, a.invt_qty
from inventory_locations a left join main_customer c
on a.company=c.company and a.customer=c.customer and a.ware_code=c.ware_code
where not exists (select 1 from zone b where b.location_code = a.location_code and b.zone_code='PM')
and a.company='M1'
and a.customer='100068'
UNION
select a.company, a.customer, c.customer_name, a.location_code, a.invt1, a.invt2, a.invt3, a.invt_qty
from inventory_locations a left join main_customer c
on a.company=c.company and a.customer=c.customer and a.ware_code=c.ware_code
where not exists (select 1 from zone b where b.location_code = a.location_code and b.zone_code='Z1')
and a.company='M1'
and a.customer='100012'
```

Table 1 - INVENTORY_LOCATIONS A

```
COMPANY | WARE_CODE |CUSTOMER   | LOCATION_CODE |INVT1  | INVT2 | INVT3     | INVT_QTY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M1      | 01        | 100012    | 0101A         |000052 | T100  | 000001001 | 60
M1      | 01        | 100012    | 0602A         |000053 | T101  | 000001002 | 60
M1      | 01        | 100068    | 0601A         |CANDY  | T200  | 000001080 | 25
M1      | 01        | 100068    | 0102A         |CANDY2 | T202  | 000001081 | 25
```

Table 2 - ZONE B

```
COMPANY | WARE_CODE |ZONE_CODE  | LOCATION_CODE
--------------------------------------------------------
M1      | 01        |PM         | 0101A
M1      | 01        |PM         | 0102A
M1      | 01        |Z1         | 0601A
M1      | 01        |Z1         | 0602A
```

Table 3 - MAIN_ITEM D

```
COMPANY | WARE_CODE | CUSTOMER   | ITEM_CODE    | ZONE_CODE
----------------------------------------------------------------
M1      | 01        | 100012    | 000052        | PM
M1      | 01        | 100012    | 000053        | PM
M1      | 01        | 100068    | CANDY         | Z1
M1      | 01        | 100068    | CANDY2        | Z1
```

Current results with above query.

```
COMPANY | CUSTOMER  | CUSTOMER_NAME | LOCATION_CODE | INVT1     | INVT2 | INVT3     | INVT_QTY
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M1      | 100012    | TEST COMP 1   | 0602A         | 000053    | T101  | 000001002 | 60
M1      | 100068    | TEST COMP 2   | 0102A         | CANDY2    | T202  | 000001081 | 25
```

Expected results with a query that doesn't use UNION to join multiple customers.

```
COMPANY | CUSTOMER   | CUSTOMER_NAME | LOCATION_CODE | INVT1    | INVT2 | INVT3     | INVT_QTY
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M1      | 100012     | TEST COMP 1   | 0602A         | 000053   | T101  | 000001002 | 60
M1      | 100068     | TEST COMP 2   | 0102A         | CANDY2   | T202  | 000001081 | 25
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and assist.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish, independent of your query?

Comment: Hi there, essentially I'm trying to compare two tables to show any mismatches.  It is easy to do with one specific customer, as I can define the customer in the query, and then link that customer to a defined zone in the where not exist sub query.  The moment I take the customer out and remove the zone from the where not exist sub query, the customers defined in locations don't have a linkage back to the ZONE table to compare any location mismatches.  Does that make sense?  I'm not the greatest at explaining, but I am trying my best.  Thank you.

Comment: The Inventory_Locations doesn't have the column zone_code, so I don't know how to get the Inventory_Location to compare the location_codes to the Zone table.  The MAIN_ITEM table does have the zone_code, so I'm trying to link the zone_code column from the MAIN_ITEM table to the INVENTORY_LOCATIONS table so it can compare to the ZONE table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the semantics of your tables and am not sure of the primary keys which means the join conditions could need to be corrected.

However, my interpretation of your goal is to find which inventory_location rows imply a combination of location code and zone that is not in the zone table.

So I would do as follows:

1. Take the inventory_location table, and add on the customer_name and zone_code with joins. I am assuming each row has only one customer and only one zone. A "with" clause is convenient to treat this as if it were a single table.
2. Then take the location and zone code combinations and see which ones are missing from the zone table with a "where not exists" clause.

I apologize in advance for any typos/syntax errors. Without actually executing it, I think it would produce your requested output.

```
with inv_loc as (
    select a.company, a.customer, c.customer_name, a.location_code, a.invt1, a.invt2, a.invt3, a.invt_qty, d.zone_code
    from inventory_locations a
    left join main_customer c on a.company=c.company and a.customer=c.customer and a.ware_code=c.ware_code
    left join main_item d on d.company = a.company and d.customer = a.customer and d.ware_code = a.ware_code and d.item_code = a.invt1
)
select
company, customer, customer_name, location_code, invt1, invt2, invt3, invt_qty
from inv_loc i
where not exists (
    select 1 from zone b
    where b.location_code = i.location_code and b.zone_code =i.zone_code
)
```

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you very much.  You interpreted it exactly as I was trying to convey it.  Using with "with" cause and treating it as a single table is exactly what I needed to do.  I was able to get the records to show exactly as I need to see.  Thank you again!! <3